# how to draw polyline on map with forward direction arrow from source to destination in android

Tags: android

I want to draw an path from source to destination on google map in android. path is nothing but an polyline with forward direction arrows from source to destination. By using compute heading method is it possible to draw...?

Comment: Do you get the bearing of the road/path in your routing data?

Comment: No...I have only Source location Lat,Lng and End Location Lat,Lng

Answer (score 0):

This is not standard in the Google Maps API, have a look here to implement it using a bitmap which is displaying an arrow in your direction: [How can I use a custom bitmap for the "you are here" point in a MyLocationOverlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753793/how-can-i-use-a-custom-bitmap-for-the-you-are-here-point-in-a-mylocationoverla)

Answer (score 0):

you have to create the List  of LatLng starting from source location to destination. You can [customize](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial#add_custom_styling_to_your_polyline) the polylines flat arrow images.

'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'  will help you to compute the heading.

[LenovoS90's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626926/android-draw-polylines-with-arrow-on-google-map-with-direction-path) will help you more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `add(LatLong)` below from `startingLatLong` till `endingLatLong`

```
mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true).add(startingLatLong ).add(endingLatLong ));
```

Comment: It only draw polyline. I have modified above code but not getting proper result.

Comment: [Draw route between two points](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-draw-path-two-points-using-google-directions-google-map-android-api-v2/)